# Path to controller is not found

Tags: php

I am very new to the MVC. I am trying to hide the index.php from the URL. I got an .htaccess file from our another team.

http://localhost/BusinessDatingApp/
When I enter the link above then the index controller is running fine which is a default controller.

When I enter this URL (http://localhost/BusinessDatingApp/city) it throws an error

```
"The requested URL /BusinessDatingApp/city was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80"
```

Here is my .htaccess file.

```
#php_flag display_errors on
#php_value error_reporting 9999

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP} !=on
#RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# force url to lowercase
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
# ensure it is not a file on the drive first
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
#RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What I am missing here? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .htaccess file is fine. But you need to give override permission to  root directory . Because by default this permission is not given,

you need to enable re-write module in apache

I have followed this steps :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache

Comment: Thank you ashish mehta thats worked for me I tried with the second answer available on the link you provided above.